# How to Block an IP address range using the .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, ip-address, access-control

I have detected that a range of IP addresses may be used in a malicious way and I don't know how to block it.

I would like to block the range 66.249.74.* from accessing my website by using the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could use:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 66.249.74.0/24
Allow from all
```

Or you could use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^66\.249\.74\.
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I want to tell you that , I use Common100 Online chat software for detect who visiting on my website page , and i always found this IP address visit 66.249.74.* . Please see the image ! http://laroute-angkor.com/IP.jpg

So what should i do ?

Comment: @MsyMarina that IP is from google http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-66-249-64-0-1/pft

Comment: Sorry, I don't know http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-66-249-64-0-1/pft
But i don't want see those IP access on my website .

Comment: @MsyMarina does Google send you virus?

Comment: I haven't receive any virus from google , but i want to make sure that this IP address is from google navigating on my webpage is normal like another website ,right ?

Comment: @MsyMarina that site I have sent above is a trusted site that tracks the owners of each IP block, it says those IP's are from google so yes you have nothing to fear.

Comment: I need that point , thank for your value time for help me clear .

Comment: Can you please explain what the /24 does?  Why the number 24?

Comment: @JBeck [you can read about it in this link, scroll down to IPv4](https://www.ripe.net/about-us/press-centre/understanding-ip-addressing)

Answer (score 16):

Use just the first 3 octets

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 66.249.74.
Allow from all
```

Answer (score 2):

I’ve just used

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 188.143.*.*
Allow from all
```

as spam attack comes from `xxx.xxx.0-80.0-80`.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to: and enter ips and it will generate the file for you.
http://www.htaccesstools.com/block-ips/

Also for example you want to block the `ip address range` you want would be:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 66.249.74.0/24
Allow from all
```

Or You Can Do:

You can indicate which addresses you wish to block using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}`.

**This is a Working Example:**

```
# BLOCK VISITORS REFERRED FROM GOOGLE.COM

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([a-z0-9-]+\.)?google\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

---

The example above uses a regular expression, so it will block:

- `https://` or `http://`
- followed by any subdomain (or none)
- followed by `google.com`
- followed by anything (or nothing)

---

The `[F]` flag means `Forbidden`. The server will return a `403 Forbidden Error`.

Comment: If anyone, like me, is wondering where the /24 comes from: google "netmask" or "subnet mask". Basically it means "24 first bits" matter, 24 = 3 x 8 bits. See http://www.dslreports.com/faq/8426

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily by adding IP Ranges to your .htaccess file by downloading the full ranges from https://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx and uploading the .hataccess back to the directory you want blocked.

I recently blocked Russia by this method cause of getting loads of spam registrations on my forum and the forum never needs any contribution from this country.

Answer (score 0):

eg:

```
<Files *>
order deny,allow
deny from 2.72.0.0/13 2.92.0.0/14 2.132.0.0/14 
</Files>
```

Great howto with ip ranges here:

http://www.wizcrafts.net/russian-blocklist.html

Also these are up to date lists of offending ip ranges.