# How do I block IPs using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ip, block

How can I stop these IP addresses from hitting my site (185.*.*.* and 93.127.*.*).
I have tried these in .htaccess:

> Order Allow,Deny
>
> Deny from 185.162.0.0/15
>
> Deny from 185.164.0.0/14
>
> Deny from 185.168.0.0/13
>
> Deny from 185.176.0.0/12
>
> Deny from 185.192.0.0/11
>
> Deny from 93.127.0.0/16
>
> Allow from all

and bots from http://tab-studio.com/en/blocking-robots-on-your-page/ but I continue to be hit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Block an IP address range using the .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483068/how-to-block-an-ip-address-range-using-the-htaccess-file)

Comment: I've read everything I have found but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Good: Edit (or create) the `.htaccess` file in the root of your server and put the following code:

```
order allow, deny
deny from 210.140.98.160
deny from 69.197.132.70
deny from 74.14.13.236
allow from all
```

Comment: Can't read what you posted and I have tried your type of statements in htaccess.  Nothing is working.

Comment: I have and it does not work in this case.  What I have shared above is basically the same code you have shared with me.    There is something going on that I do not understand.  This should be basic stuff but with all my tries, nothing has worked.

Comment: I just checked the IP address on my server and they are different from the ones generated from the code in my pages.  The code is provided by StatCounter.com.  Maybe that is the reason I cannot block them but I do not understand what is going on.