# Bot Spamming Filter Requests on Woocommerce Website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, woocommerce

A bot is spamming my woocommerce websites with the same GET filter request. This causes my error logs to get really big and fills up my server disk space. How do I prevent this kind of request?

I've attempted to block the IP but eventually the bot shows up with a different IP and performs the same request.

I noticed GET request like this showing up on my apache.access.log for my website.

```
148.251.92.39 - - [19/Aug/2019:11:04:17 +0000] 
"GET /product-category/some-category/?filter_flavours=flavor1,flavor2,...,flavor15
HTTP/1.0" 403 859
```

The bot starts by checking my robots.txt

```
108.59.8.80 - - [19/Aug/2019:11:52:48 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 67
```

The bot looks like it filters for every possible item that can be covered by that category, and then spams that GET requests as many times as it can.

Some of the IPs that made similar get requests can be found on abuseipdb.com

https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/144.76.236.112

These requests create a strange database query.

```
# Time: 2019-08-19T10:40:36.958807Z
# User@Host: db-user[] @ localhost []  Id: 111
# Query_time: 0.762636  Lock_time: 0.196198 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use my-db;
SET timestamp=1566211236;
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'a:333623:{i:0;b:0;s:32:\"c3dfc0f6173112a56bf12c79c81c5dfd\";
a:0:{}s:32:"13112848b4e9632f77a38f69b9898a60\";a:0:{}s:32:
"b3f4286ca803f55c6ee15185d8f6f8e2\"

... this is repeated for a huge amount of lines ...

"8d3fedbfb7a3e823df7443f0595dee4f\";a:0:{}}' WHERE `option_name` =
'_transient_wc_layered_nav_counts_pa_effects';
```

I can block a specific IP when it starts making requests like that but I want to block any requests that behave like that. Is there any way to do this? I'm running a linux server.

Answer (score 1):

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 66.249.74.0/24
Allow from all
Or
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 66.249.74.0/24
Allow from all
```

You can block a range of similar ips in your htaccess file

[How to Block an IP address range using the .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483068/how-to-block-an-ip-address-range-using-the-htaccess-file)

Comment: I know I can block the IP address range, but since posting this the same bot seems to have made similar requests from different IPs around the world.

Comment: Have you tired the Akismet plugin for this. or other spam blockers plugins and also use google or other captcha.

Comment: Ill try askimet and see if it does anything, im not sure if captcha would do anything in this case.